# How can I use a foreach loop to delete all of the control in a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

Here's the code I have:

```
private void ClearSearchResults()
    {
        foreach (Control X in panel1.Controls)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Remove(X);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when I run this method, only a single item is deleted, then if I click on a button again so the method can run again, another is deleted.

If I have 10 control in my panel, I'd have to click the "Delete" button on my program many times for all the control to be deleted.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: the type of panel should be irrelevant, the above code could be run on ANY controls collection. i.e. the Form itself or any type of container (including user controls)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
private void ClearSearchResults()
{
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Edited to emphasize the CKret comment.

Comment: Yeah it works. Really wierd. Why doesn't the foreach statement do the trick though?

Comment: @Papuccino1, my answer might explain that.

Comment: As Star R said: It doesn't work with a foreach since you are changing the IEnumerable while you are iterating throught it. That is forbidden.

Comment: @Papuccino1: Check out my answer for the typical workaround.  This issue happens with nearly ANY collection and "foreach"

Comment: Just to be clear: Remove the foreach loop alltogether. I.e. do not put panel1.Controls.Clear(); inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 16):

You, in general, can't remove from a collection while iterating an enumerable generated from it.  Instead of using foreach, the typical approach is to use a for loop working backwards:

```
private void ClearSearchResults()
{
    for(int i=panel1.Controls.Count-1;i>=0;--i) {
        panel1.Controls.RemoveAt(i);        
        // or
        // Control X = panel1.Controls[i];
        // panel1.Controls.Remove(X);
    }
}
```

However, in this case, just use clear:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: +1 this is what i was getting at, thanks for being less lazy than me Reed. :)

Comment: Hehehe, I didn't see yours when I started, or I probably wouldn't have bothered :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are changing the IEnumareble when you remove an item from it while iterating it.

Try to use a simple for loop instead of a foreach.

Comment: This is the correct explanation.  You cannot alter a collection while enumerating it.

Comment: If removing all items then you should use a regular for loop and loop backwards. Otherwise you will remove every other item and then get an OutOfBounds exception.

Comment: @CKret, yes Reed's example illustrates how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

For a start you shouldn't edit the IEnumerable collection within a foreach loop. You should be using a for loop or a while.

I.e.

```
private void ClearSearchResults()
    {
        while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            panel1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
```

or just use:

```
 panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: It will work. Since if there is atleast one element in the collection then there is always an element at index 0.

Comment: @Stan R - it's a while loop, so it won't need an indexer

Comment: @GenericTypeTea, oops I completely glossed over that. Im going to leave my comment there for sheer humiliation.. and +1 for you.

Comment: @Stan R, no worries chap, we all make mistakes. You should see some of mine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know the kind of panel you use, you can generally call `panel1.Controls.Clear`

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void ClearSearchResults()
        {
            foreach (Control X in panel1.Controls)
            {
                panel1.Controls.Remove(X);
            }
            if (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
            { 
                ClearSearchResults();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't use `Remove` because it breaks the iterator so simple solution would be something like this :

```
var controls = in c from panel1.Controls select c;
foreach(Controls _control in controls)
{
   panel1.Controls.Remove(_control);
}
```

but of course you don't want to stick to Loop then go ahead and use `panel1.Controls.Clear()`

Comment: Of course this would not work as when you remove a control you change the existing controls index.  You are also looping too much.  Imagine having 2 controls your loop says start at 0 and end at index = 2.  The minute you remove one control you actually have changed the index of all current controls.  The solution is to simply loop for the number of controls but remove at index 0.

int n;
            n = panel1.Controls.Count-1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
            {
                Control c = panel1.Controls[0];
                panel1.Controls.Remove(c);
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
            int n;
            n = panel1.Controls.Count-1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
            {
                Control c = panel1.Controls[0];
                panel1.Controls.Remove(c);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (panel1.Controls.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(c);
    }
}
```

Another way !